# How do I change the name of the hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, finder

Right now my hard drive is called "Macintosh HD." How do I change it to something cool like "Death Killer"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can rename a file or a drive by selecting it by clicking on it, pressing "return", typing the new name, and pressing "return" again to set it. There are a few restricted characters, like `:`, but for the most part you can name it anything you want.

[image]

Comment: Wow, way easier than I thought..

Comment: @Ben Yep, Apple makes it pretty easy

Comment: In the earliest versions of Mac OS (before it was called Mac OS, just System 1, System 2, etc.) it was even easier to rename, which resulted in many systems with oddly renamed hard drives.